# Calculus : Radius of convergence of a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I've the sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ define as $a_0=a_1=1$ with
$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}, \ a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{n+1}$$

I need to find the radius of convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}a_nx^n$.
My trick was to define
$$
w_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
Hence with the definition
$$
w_n=1+\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)w_{n-1}}
$$
I've shown that **if** $(w_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges then it converges to $1$. How can I show that $(w_n)$ converges ? Any help ?

Comment: Use $a_{n+1} \geqslant a_n$, whence $w_n \geqslant 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$w_n
=1+\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)w_{n-1}}
$,
then
$w_n > 1$.

Therefore
$w_n < 1+\dfrac1{n+1}$.

Therefore
$w_n \to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show $1\le a_n \le n$ for all $n.$ That will tell you what the ROC is.